# Concatenate columns within different tables based on criteria

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to concatenate sales IDs onto a column of sales items.

```
#4 items that are for sale 
SaleItems<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"))

#sales IDs for these 4 items
SalesIDs<-data.frame(Appliance=rep(c("Radio", "Laptop", "TV", "Fridge"), times=c(5,5,5,5)), ID=c(120:139))
```

The result that I want (for presentation purposes) is to concatenate the sales IDs onto the SaleItems$Appliance column (in between brackets) as per the below example:

```
SaleItemsIDs<-data.frame(Appliance=c("Radio (120, 121, 122, 123, 124)", "Laptop (125, 126, 127, 128, 129)", "TV (130,131,132,133,134)", "Fridge (135, 136, 137, 138, 139)"))
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Concatenating basically means stacking. Perhaps you meant merge? Also, your SalesIDs dataframe won't compile because of the uneven row numbers. Btw, in your output, you probably don't wan't to code distinct numeric values within the same string. Either way, implementation aside, would you be able to possibly elaborate on what it is that you want to accomplish? Do you want to group IDs by appliance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can first group by 'Appliance' and `paste` the 'ID' together, then `paste` the 'Appliance' to create a single string

```
library(dplyr)
SalesIDs %>%
   group_by(Appliance) %>% 
   summarise(ID = toString(ID)) %>%
   transmute(Appliance = paste(Appliance, " (", ID, ")", sep=""))
```